# Data mapping between two sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am looking for a formula based solution to map information from one sheet that is imported using `IMPORTRANGE` to another sheet (what a bad explanation). But an example might be easier to understand - the following two sheets are given:

#### Sheet 1

| Color | Formula column |
| --- | --- |
| red | =??? |
| green | =??? |
| blue | =??? |

#### Sheet 2 (imported from another file with `IMPORTRANGE`)

| color | details1 | details2 | peter | susan | john | christin |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| red | not important | not important either | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |
| green | not important | not important either | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |

And this is what I want the result should look like

#### Sheet 1 (expected)

| Color | Formula column |
| --- | --- |
| red | peter, christin |
| green | peter, susan |
| blue | nobody |

Sadly, I am not really good with the formula stuff. I've created an Apps Script but since the lookup data in sheet two has more than 1000 rows it always ends up in a exectuion timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use:

`=BYROW(A2:A,LAMBDA(ax,if(ax="",,IFERROR(JOIN(", ",query({LAMBDA(bez,QUERY(INDEX(SPLIT(FLATTEN({importrange(bez,"Sheet2!A2:A")&"|"&importrange(bez,"Sheet2!D1:G1")&"|"&importrange(bez,"Sheet2!D2:G")}),"|",0,0)),"Select * Where Col1!='' AND Col3=1"))("[SHEET 2 SPREADSHEET ID]")},"select Col2 Where Col1='"&ax&"'")),"nobody"))))`

- Replace **[SHEET 2 SPREADSHEET ID]** in the formula with the relevant sheet ID

[image]

Comment: also the tab name (in Sheet 2) is given as 'Sheet2'; you may also change that accordingly.

Comment: **it works :)** just to make sure i get a basic understandig of that magic formula... `SPLIT/FLATTEN` builds a three column matrix: first column contains the color, second column the person and the third column the state (zero or one). Whats the deal with `INDEX` - it always targets row/cell 0 of that matrix? The inner `QUERY` removes all rows with state 0 and keeps state 1. The outer `QUERY` reads the name of the person according to the current row color. Also not sure about the outer `LAMBDA` "ax" ? It calls the inner `LAMBDA` "bez" until the first cell of column `A` that is empty?

Comment: index is just akin to arrayformula here. outer lambda is for targeting all rows that has data in them. inner lambda is just to not keep repeating the spreadsheet ID multiple times and make the formula appear convoluted or so...

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=INDEX(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A7:A10, LAMBDA(x, {OFFSET(x, 1,, 9^9, 1 ), 
 BYROW(IF(OFFSET(x, 1, 3, 9^9, 4)*1=1, OFFSET(x,, 3, 1, 4), ), 
 LAMBDA(y, TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, y)))})(A1:G5), 2, )))
```

[image]